# Change css style HTML5 form required attribute required message

Tags: jquery, css, html

i work with `RTLbootstrap` for `RTL` project. now i have any form with **HTML5 form required attribute required message**. in action i have this ballon for input:

[image]

I need To change Like This For RTL:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="controls">
  <input class="span4" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title"  value=""  required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(\'User ID is a must\')">
</div>
```

**NOTE:This is not custom tooltip or ballon! if we add required html tag in form input. before submit form `HTML5 form required attribute` show this ballon message automaticly. I need To edit/change/Set CSS For validation message?**

How To change Display Of required field message for show in `right` of `input` field?

Comment: All I see that changed here is the triangle portion of the tool tip... can you just edit that within the "span4" class or the "controls" class (wherever the tool tip resides)??

Comment: This changes from browser to browser, for instance, you are seeing this on Firefox, but Chrome has something completely different, and so does IE. The only way to ensure this will work and look the same way in all browsers, is to build your own validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome does not allow styling form validation bubbles anymore:

[See Details](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=259050)

Firefox has no way to style the error bubbles

[See Details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML/Element/Input#section_5)

Answer (score 0):

hey i found a link here and they have used this trick.They have appended a class to the input type. and displayed message there .Hope that helps after little customization.
working codepen:  http://codepen.io/smarty_tech/pen/ONZRVp

```
<form id="frm" action="action">
<div>
<label>Email</label>
  <input type="email" required="required"/><span class="theTooltip">Invalid email</span>
 </div>
 <div>
  <button formnovalidate="formnovalidate">OK</button>
</div>
```

```
 document.querySelector('#frm').addEventListener('submit', e => {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.currentTarget.classList.add('submitted');
 });

  body
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif
 display: flex
 flex-direction: column
align-items: center
 justify-content: center
overflow: hidden
width: 100%
 height: 100vh
  background orange

 form > div
  position: relative
  margin-bottom: 10px

 .theTooltip
  $bgcolor = rgba(black, 0.7)
  $arrow = 10
  $radius = 5
  $maxWidth = 250
  $padding = 15
  backface-visibility: hidden
  will-change: opacity, visibility
  max-width: $maxWidth * 1px
  border-radius: $radius * 1px
  background-color: $bgcolor
  padding: $padding * 1px
  color: white
  box-sizing: border-box
  display: inline-block
  position: absolute
  transform-style: preserve-3d
  transform: translate(15%, -50%)
  top: 50%;
  left: auto
  right: auto
  bottom: auto
  visibility: hidden
  margin: 0
  opacity: 0
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out
  z-index: 100
  &:after
  content: ''
  position: absolute
  width: 0
   height: 0
  top: 50%
margin-top: $arrow * -1px
left: $arrow * -1px
border-top: $arrow * 1px solid transparent
border-bottom: $arrow * 1px solid transparent
border-right: $arrow * 1px solid $bgcolor

  label
 display: inline-block
 vertical-align: center

input
background: white
border: 1px solid transparent
cursor: pointer
display: inline-block
overflow: visible
margin: 0
outline: 0
vertical-align: center
text-decoration: none
width: auto
border-radius: 3px
cursor: text
padding: 7px
&:focus
&:active
outline: none

 .submitted
  input
  &:invalid
    border: 1px solid red
    ~ .theTooltip
       visibility: visible
      opacity: 1
  &:valid
    ~ .theTooltip
      transition: opacity 0.3s, visibility 0s 0.3s
```

Answer (score -2):

[Example of Message with only css3](http://css-tricks.com/bubble-point-tooltips-with-css3-jquery/)

Code :

```
.tooltip, .arrow:after {
  background: black;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.tooltip {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 14px "Helvetica Neue", Sans-Serif;
  font-stretch: condensed;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px black;
}
.arrow {
  width: 70px;
  height: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -35px;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.arrow:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   left: 20px;
   top: -20px;
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 5px 9px -9px black,5px 6px 9px -9px black;
   -moz-box-shadow: 6px 5px 9px -9px black,5px 6px 9px -9px black;
   box-shadow: 6px 5px 9px -9px black,5px 6px 9px -9px black;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform:      rotate(45deg); 
}
.tooltip.active {
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition:    all 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition:     all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition:      all 0.2s ease;
}
.tooltip.out {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```