# Is it possible to change the text color of HTML 5 required function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the text color of required function.Is it possible to do?

For example,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <form>
    <input rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" required/>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When we run the above code,when we click on submit without entering text box it give error as "Please fill out this field".This is black in color.But, I want this should be in red color.Is it possible to change the color?

Comment: Please provide full HTML snippet and JavaScript to get suggestion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change css style HTML5 form required attribute required message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892240/change-css-style-html5-form-required-attribute-required-message)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478800/override-css-for-html5-form-validation-required-popup

Answer (score 1):

Required is just an attribute so probably we can apply the style.

Use this style:

```
input:required { 
     background-color: #000;
     color:#ffffff;
}
```

or

```
input[required] {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```